# PHP: How can I get protected values of an object?

Tags: php, ebay-api

My Call gets back: print_r($response)

```
GetItemResponseType Object
(
    [Item:protected] => ItemType Object
        (
            [ApplicationData:protected] => 651034.9.3011
            [BuyerProtection:protected] => ItemEligible
            [BuyItNowPrice:protected] => AmountType Object
                (
                    [attributeValues] => Array
                        (
                            [currencyID] => EUR
                        )

                    [value:protected] => 0.0
                )

            [Country:protected] => DE

        )

)
```

I read this ([How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)), but I can't reproduce the solution.

How can I get the value of Country with i.e. this:

```
   function accessProtected($obj, $prop) {
      $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
      $property = $reflection->getProperty($prop);
      $property->setAccessible(true);
      return $property->getValue($obj);
    }
```

I get nothing, if I call:

```
echo accessProtected($response, 'Country');
```

Regards, Matthias

Comment: It's protected for a reason - there is very likely a "getter" method to retrieve this information already, it's doubtful you need to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get protected property of object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to my question is:

```
echo $response->Item->Country;
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You should create getter and setter functions which are public or static in your class.

Comment: Ok, I look for a getter method of this ebay api call.