# Fetch Certain Values from a PHP Array Response

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to extract `["details"]` from an Array so that it shows

```
Array Value 1=address
Array Value 2=no_match
Array Value 3=address_risk
Array Value 4=low
```

**I tried the following but it doesnt return any value**

```
foreach ($person as $key => $val) {
    print "$key = $val\n";
}
```

So i should be able to query the Array value `if address="no_match" Print "no match"`
[image]

**Array Value $person**

```
object(TestScore\Person)#1 (2) {
  ["_values":protected]=>
  array(25) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(24) "57100c7832366100030011e0"
    ["object"]=>
    string(6) "person"
    ["created_at"]=>
    int(1460669560)
    ["updated_at"]=>
    int(1460669560)
    ["status"]=>
    string(5) "valid"
    ["livemode"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["phone_number"]=>
    NULL
    ["ip_address"]=>
    NULL
    ["birth_day"]=>
    int(1)
    ["birth_month"]=>
    int(1)
    ["birth_year"]=>
    int(1990)
    ["name_first"]=>
    string(4) "Jane"
    ["name_middle"]=>
    NULL
    ["name_last"]=>
    string(3) "Doe"
    ["address_street1"]=>
    string(17) "123 Something Ave"
    ["address_street2"]=>
    NULL
    ["address_city"]=>
    string(12) "Newton Falls"
    ["address_subdivision"]=>
    string(2) "OH"
    ["address_postal_code"]=>
    string(5) "44444"
    ["address_country_code"]=>
    string(2) "US"
    ["document_type"]=>
    string(3) "ssn"
    ["document_value"]=>
    string(4) "0000"
    ["note"]=>
    NULL
    ["details"]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
      ["address"]=>
      string(8) "no_match"
      ["address_risk"]=>
      string(3) "low"
      ["identification"]=>
      string(8) "no_match"
      ["date_of_birth"]=>
      string(9) "not_found"
      ["ofac"]=>
      string(8) "no_match"
      ["pep"]=>
      string(8) "no_match"
    }
    ["question_sets"]=>
    object(TestScore\QuestionSet)#4 (3) {
      ["_existing":"TestScore\QuestionSet":private]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_values":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(24) "57100c7832366100030011e0"
      }
      ["_unsavedValues":protected]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
  ["_unsavedValues":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
NULL
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get protected property of object in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This:**

```
foreach ($person as $key => $val) {
    print "$key = $val\n";
}
```

**Should be:**

```
foreach ($person["details"] as $key => $val) {
    print "$key = $val\n";
}
```

**Reason:**
To pull an array from an array that is nested you need zoom in similar to a file system, where the difference is [first_array][second_array]...

Comment: took me a while to figure out arrays also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the _values property is protected and is not visible when iterating from outside the class. For an explanation of a couple ways to access the protected property anyway see this question:

[How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)