# how to get array value from php object

Tags: php

I am trying to get the "Id" value from an object an API returns.

This is what I get back from an the array `$IS_user[0]` which the API returns:

```
object(Contact)#165 (5) {
  ["customFieldFormId"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["fields":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(7) "Contact"
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(78) {
    ["Id"]=>
    '1' 
.................
```

I want the Id so tried `$IS_user[0]->data['Id']`

But it broke.

Comment: its a protected property, check the API if its has a specific method to get the ID

Comment: Have you tried casting it as an array: $array = (array) $IS_user[0]->data; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php. Note: this is a hack.

Comment: @Nitin If you cast it to an array, shouldn't it be `[chr(0).'*'.chr(0).'data']` instead of `->data`?

Comment: @Barmar you are right. My mistake.