# Simple way to assign :protected response values to php variables?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, request, response

Here’s part of a var_dump of a response to a request. We’ll call it $response:

```
object(NeverBounce\Object\VerificationObject)#4 (1) {
["response":protected]=>
array(9) {
["status"]=>
string(7) "success"
["result"]=>
string(7) "invalid"
...
```

I know how to access the array values of $response and assign them to variables using:

```
$var1 = response->[status];
$var2 = response->[result];
```

Except for one little problem... The :protected appended to response.

How do I refer to status and result when assigning them to $var1 and $var2? The syntax above doesn’t work because of the protected state of the array. 
I did read in the manual and other posts about protected, private, public but being new at this, it made little sense.

Perhaps I am fantasizing but it seems there must be a simple way to do this.

Please advise. All help and comments appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) which is present in `PHP`:

Wikipedia definition of Reflection ~

> The ability of a computer program to examine and modify the
>   structure and behavior (specifically the values, meta-data, properties
>   and functions) of the program at runtime. [[Reflection
>   (computer_programming)]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)

In this case you may want to use reflection to examine the properties of the object and set as accessible the protected property _data

This is an example on how to get your `private/protected` parameter using Reflection with PHP:

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass($object);
$classProperty = $reflector->getProperty('_data');
$classProperty->setAccessible(true);
$data = $classProperty->getValue($object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast your object to array and access it like normal array values, something like this

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
$status = $array['response']['status'];
$result = $array['response']['result'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I took your suggestion and got the array as expected. However, there is an asterisk preceding the property name now. $email_addr_valid = $nb_request->[*response][result];
   echo $email_addr_valid; yields an empty screen. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try to print it without aesterik like [response][result] ?