# Get Value of Protected Object in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following object...

```
Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\o\MonthlySearchVolume Object
(
    [year:protected] => 2018
    [month:protected] => 10
    [count:protected] => 450000
)
```

And I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the year, month, and count out and into a regular array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this response : [How to get protected property of object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334749/10744028) by [Álvaro-gonzález](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%C3%81lvaro-gonz%C3%A1lez)

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

If you need to access the property from outside, pick one:

- Don't declare it as protected, make it public instead
- Write a couple of functions to get and set the value (getters and setters)

If you don't want to modify the original class (because it's a third-party library you don't want to mess) create a custom class that extends the original one:

```
class MonthlySearchVolume {}
```

... and add your getter/setter there.

Comment: If you are going to copy somone elses answer at least format it the same

Comment: Plus mention the original author