# Get price value of the WP object

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using NAME YOUR PRICE PLUGIN and in the Checkout page of my Wordpress site, i need to get the price value (300) of this Wordpress Object. So i ahev set a loop in my functions.php.
But i don't know how to do to target this specifc attribute.
Thanks for help

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];

        print_r ($values['data']);
    }
```

```
    WC_Product_Simple Object
(
    [object_type:protected] => product
    [post_type:protected] => product
    [cache_group:protected] => products
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [name] => Faire un don
            [slug] => don
            [date_created] => WC_DateTime Object
                (
                    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
                    [date] => 2019-10-25 11:15:27.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/Paris
                )

            [status] => publish
            [featured] => 
                         [sku] => don
            ...
            [purchase_note] => 
        )

    [supports:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => ajax_add_to_cart
        )

    [id:protected] => 969
    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
            [price] => 300
            [sale_price] => 300
            [regular_price] => 300
        )

    [object_read:protected] => 1
    [extra_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

        )
)
```

Comment: The `WC_Product_Simple` class has the `get_price()` method. So, `$product->get_price()`?

Comment: thanks i am afraid this won't work because [price] attribute (from Name Your Price) is not the same than [price] returned by get_price()

Comment: There is a first in  [data:protected] and a second in [changes:protected]. I need the second.

Comment: You can try it this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php… OR you could see how this is stored in the database and read/dislay it from there

Comment: thanks i used your link and it works fine !!! how can i indicate it's the solution ?

Comment: it is best to post the answer you have found to your question yourself (apply your working method). You can refer to the link and then mark your own answer as the solution. Regards

Comment: the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php

Comment: yes I know. But that way you can mark your own question as solved, otherwise you don't have that option. 
There are several answers to that url, describe which one you used I would say.

Comment: please i don"t see button to mark as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the previous answers just targeted the frist attribute PRICE, i finally found a solution with this method:

```
function accessProtected($obj, $prop) {
  $reflection = new ReflectionClass($obj);
  $property = $reflection->getProperty($prop);
  $property->setAccessible(true);
  return $property->getValue($obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 
            echo "<b>".$_product->get_title().'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);
            echo "  Price: ".$price."<br>";
        }
```

Comment: it only get the frist price attribute. the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php